# Python and BeautifulSoup scraping in HTML email

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to using beautifulsoup and python, therefore my question might seem simple or like I am misunderstanding something, so please bear with me and be patient.

I have an O365 mailbox which I need to scrape at a set time period and pull the body of the email out into a JSON string which is then passed via API to a web monitor.  I have this working with a number of other sources but for one email I cant get the needed details.

The raw email which is causing the problem is as follow's:-

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"><strong>'ExternalCon'</strong>  detected on <strong>1</strong> externally facing devices.

<br><br><br>

<a href="https:///">https://</a>
<br><br>
<br>
------------------------------ Query Results (up to 500 records) ------------------------------<br>
<br>
&quot;ip&quot;,&quot;uuid&quot;,&quot;repositoryID&quot;,&quot;score&quot;,&quot;total&quot;,&quot;severityInfo&quot;,&quot;severityLow&quot;,&quot;severityMedium&quot;,&quot;severityHigh&quot;,&quot;severityCritical&quot;,&quot;macAddress&quot;,&quot;policyName&quot;,&quot;pluginSet&quot;,&quot;netbiosName&quot;,&quot;dnsName&quot;,&quot;osCPE&quot;,&quot;biosGUID&quot;,&quot;tpmID&quot;,&quot;mcafeeGUID&quot;,&quot;lastAuthRun&quot;,&quot;lastUnauthRun&quot;,&quot;hostUniqueness&quot;,&quot;vulnBar&quot;,&quot;repositoryIDs&quot;<br>

&quot;***.***.***.***&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;External IPs&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;1&quot;,&quot;1&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;8d6b2cf3-1218-18685270/External_Con (from IO)&quot;,&quot;101022242455&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:X.X&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;2605561676&quot;,&quot;repositoryID,ip,dnsName&quot;,&quot;1:0:0:0:0&quot;,&quot;4&quot;
```

Now I want to output the following information:-

```
ExternalCon detected on X externally facing devices.

ip -> X.X.X.X
total -> X
policyname -> X
osCPE -> X
```

The code I have so far is below, I know it is nasty and there will be much better ways to do it so please any advice would be welcome.

```
def extcon():
    logfile.write(currentDT.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f") + " - STARTING IMPORT LOOP FOR ExtCon- lookng for folder . . . ")       
    timed = calendar.timegm(item.datetime_received.timetuple())
    ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', item.body) 
    r = item.body
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    test = soup
    links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
    descr = soup.text 
    test1 = item.body.split('strong')
    test2 = soup.prettify #for string in test.stripped_strings:
    test = item.body.split('&quot;')
    head = '# ' + test1[1] + "\n\r" + "\n\r" \
        + '-------------------------------------' + "\n\r" + "\n\r" \
        + test1[1] + test1[2] + test1[3] + "\n\r" + "\n\r" 
    head = head.replace('<', '')
    head = head.replace('>', '')
    head = head.replace('\'', '')
    head = head.replace('/', '')
    body = test[1] + ' -> ' + test[2] + "\n\r" + "\n\r" \
        + test[3] + ' -> ' + test[26] + "\n\r" + "\n\r" \
        + test[4] + ' -> ' + test[28] + "\n\r" + "\n\r" \
        + test[11] + ' -> ' + test[35] + "\n\r" + "\n\r" \
        + test[15] + ' -> ' + test[39] + "\n\r" + "\n\r"
```

What I get is the test split breaking apart the email and giving me a list of 97 items, but when I try to call them individually to add them to the 'body' var it is showing me a lot more then I would have expected and I'm also not sure how to deal with when the tool finds more than a single extcon.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.